# Update total amount of cart in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to implement coupon and needs to show discounted price.
I want to update the value of `$this->cart->total()` instead of updating products.

I know that `$this->cart->total()` will return total amount, but how to update this amount?

Comment: Please, copy the source code of your try. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can just update it in the session.

```
$_SESSION['cart_contents']['cart_total'] = INSERT CORRECT TOTAL HERE;
```

Or you can create a new cart item in your session called coupon_discount and add that value there.

Then when you show that value in your view you can just show one minus the other.

Answer (score 0):

You add additional fields in your cart like this:

```
            $discount = 50.00; //depends on your logic

            $data = array(
                    'id'=> random_string('alnum', 16).time(),
                    'product_code' => $product_id_,
                    'qty'     => $qty,
                    'price'   => $price-$discount, //your cart total() is net of discount already
                    'orig_price'=>$orig_price,
                    'name'    => $product_name,
                    'photo' => $photo,
                    'category' => $category,
                    'uom'=>$uom,
            );

            $this->cart->product_name_safe = FALSE; //this is okay because i got the name from our database not from user input.
            $this->cart->product_id_rules = '[:print:]'; //this will allow special chars in product code 
            $this->cart->product_name_rules = '[:print:]'; //this will allow special chars in product name 
            $this->cart->insert($data); //add item in your cart.
```